# What's the tangible benefit of titles like FBCS, CEng, FRSE, FIET, FREng in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, titles

I am an associate professor in computer science. I see a lot of academics with titles like FBCS, CEng, FRSE, FIET, FREng. I was wondering, what's the tangible benefit of these titles? I know that memberships of things like ACM and IEEE give access to online libraries and discounted registration rates. But it is unclear to me what benefits these titles bring.

Comment: How are titles relate to discounts? ACM gives discounts to students but it isn't based on titles? Some things you list are honorifics. I'm guessing that FBCS is Fellow of the British Computer Society. That likely assumes membership.

Comment: If you are a senior ACM member, you get discounted registration rates at ACM sponsored conferences. Most of the titles I list above require submitting an application and paying an annual fee.

Comment: Are you asking about Qualifications; Degrees; Titles, or about Memberships? 
CEng is a Qualification; FBCS is a Membership (possibly honorary, ie free) ....

Comment: @MohamedKhamis Is that true? All ACM sponsored events I know of have a standard member rate, and the only discount is for student members. It would be strange to imagine to give a special rebate to senior members or fellows, since these also do not tend to be the people who need a discounted rate.

Answer (score 33):

I'm going to be pedantic here: These are not titles but [*postnominals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_post-nominal_letters_(United_Kingdom)). Titles always precede a name (like Dr. for example).

They are used to indicate professional qualifications in the same way that using B.Sc and M.Sc are used as  a postnominal to indicate qualification of a Bachelor's or Master's degree, which you are familiar with. A degree of professional experience is required to gain these professional qualifications which will occur beyond an academic qualification.

What are the benefits? Use of these titles indicates several things:

- They indicate the subject area one specialises in
- They indicate that someone has practiced in that area for a period of time beyond a university degree
- They indicate your level of experience is recognised by your professional peers

Now for some detail:

CEng: A Chartered Engineer; awarded by the Engineering Council
FBCS: Fellow of the British Computer Society; shows engineering in computing in some form. Fellow is a senior level. MBCS would be a lower level.
FRSE: Fellow of the Royal Society of Edinburgh; Recognised as a senior Scientist in Scotland.
FIET: Fellow of the IET (formerly IEE) which shows some form of electronic engineering is recognised at a higher level.

and so on.

There are also Professional titles that are used as pre-nominals. Eur Ing is one and is used in the German style (even in the UK) so you can be:

Eur Ing Prof Person

(I have both pre-nominal titles and post-nominal letters)

Comment: +1 It's worth noting that not all postnomials are equal in terms of their significance. Some (e.g. FRS - Fellow of the Royal Society) are highly-prized and awarded for high distinction. Others are available to anyone with a relevant degree and a willingness to pay an annual fee.

Comment: @avid And some postnomials are just 'BS'.

Comment: A small note - the IET since its rebranding as the Institute of Engineering Technology covers all engineering disciplines, not just electrical. I know many fellows within the IET with no electrical background at all.

Comment: Just to add to the above post. FHEA is often seen (Fellow of the Advance HE - formerly Higher Education Academy) is essentially a teaching qualification and is often required for UK academics now. Chartership (CEng) with the relevant bodies IStructE (Institution of Structural Engineers), ICE (Institution of Civil Engineers), etc is a factor for the accreditation of engineering degree programs (a minimum number of staff members must hold chartership).

Answer (score 17):

Following on to the excellent answer by Brian Tompsett above, I'd like to highlight that there are a [rather large number of learned societies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_post-nominal_letters_(United_Kingdom)#Fellowship_or_membership_of_learned_societies,_academies_or_professional_institutions) that one can join or may be relevant to an academic discipline, and that the relative importance of these varies hugely on a sector-by-sector basis.

For example, being a fellow of the Royal Astronomical Society, a fellow of the Institute of Physics, or -- better yet! -- the Royal Society is a significant national or international honour: most university astronomy / physics departments would not have 100% of their academic staff with such a qualification, for example (and [FRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fellow_of_the_Royal_Society) in particular is *very* highly prized). Displaying these postnomials in a formal setting conveys some degree of objective evaluation of the quality of one's work -- for FRS in particular it is a *significant* demonstration of excellence (who wouldn't want to be in a club with ~280 Nobel laureates and many of the great scientific names in history?). There are also some practical benefits to membership: beyond journal access (which is a significant boon to those in industry or for those whose universities do not subscribe to the journal of interest), continuing professional development, and frequently a professional e-mail address, most learned bodies have a tax break on their membership fees (you can add them to your personal allowance, provided they are on [an approved list](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/professional-bodies-approved-for-tax-relief-list-3/approved-professional-organisations-and-learned-societies)), free or discounted training courses, a variety of "perks" (such as free or discounted insurance) and a (usually surprisingly good) society magazine.

One "big" reason a lot of academics join these organisations is because it often makes you eligible to apply for grant funding from them. Some may join because they have benefited from grant funding and wish to contribute something back (somewhat unusually, I personally was given £4k by the IOP as an undergraduate student as part of a bursary scheme). Frequently an academic conference will be organised with a rate that is "discounted" for members and significantly increased in price for those who are not members. This encourages those with an interest in the field to pay the (usually quite small) subscription fees (and also provides a pathway to have them reimbursed by their employers, although this is complicated from a tax point of view)

In contrast, in medicine, fellowship of the relevant Royal College of a medical speciality -- for example the Royal College of Anaesthetists -- is *far* more common, comparatively speaking, because it is a highly practical and valued qualification: essentially (high-level) doctors who are anaesthetists trained in the UK will hold the "final FRCA" because ["they [are] required to pass this examination during ST3-5 (6 months through ST5 [i.e. approximately 3-5 years after starting training in anaesthetics]), otherwise training may be delayed or stopped".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fellowship_of_the_Royal_College_of_Anaesthetists) This is a professional exam and essentially confers a license to practice: candidates are only allowed to take the (notoriously difficult) exam six times and failing it then would end their career (in anaesthetics) -- quite a different outcome to failing to get "brownie points" for an already extant academic career. This is in addition to the more "general" set of other exams and qualifications that doctors are required to obtain -- at the very least, membership of the royal college of physicians or surgeons (as befits their training) which *itself* can be "upgraded" to fellowship but only for "distinguished consultants" and others whom the royal college considers to be worthy of the accolade -- typically academics in medicine, SAS doctors, or those who have been recommended by their peers. As well as being legally mandated, a lot of the time membership of these bodies confers with it some degree of indemnity insurance, but the specifics of this vary (and get quite complicated). The other perks listed above are present, but usually to a lesser degree.  I should also say that arrangements in Scotland are similar but distinct entirely because of historical reasons (arguably *all* of the above exists entirely because of historical reasons! It's a glorified apprenticeship scheme!)

As a consequence of this requirement, academics in medicine tend to accumulate a *lot* of professional body memberships and with them postnomials: the (legally required) first degree in medicine (e.g. BmBCh), a later (legally required) MRCP / FRCP or similar, specialist training qualifications (FRCA), an optional PhD, DPhil or MD, and quite often *then* membership of other related learned bodies if relevant to their research or practice interests (e.g. our hypothetical anaesthetist interested in Intensive Care Medicine might well also become...a Fellow of the [Faculty of Intensive Care Medicine](https://www.ficm.ac.uk/) -- or perhaps may apply to join the [Difficult Airway Society](https://das.uk.com/) -- or any one of a number of different options).

I am an academic and a member of two UK substantial professional bodies, one that you would have to be in my field to have ever heard of, and one international one. The benefits I get are indemnity insurance, a professional email address, a vague sense of recognition from my peers, and I have been invited to provide advice to the (UK) government on areas I am professionally competent in through them. I also have the ability to walk into one of a number of beautiful buildings in central London and have a free cup of coffee, should the desire overwhelm me to do so.

I guess, therefore, in summary:

- Postnominal titles like FRS, FRSE, FREng, FRSC, FInstP, etc, convey prestige and an (allegedly) objective evaluation of one's work in certain fields -- that is arguably their primary purpose
- Relatedly to the above point, membership of learned societies or professional bodies allows networking, peer recognition, and formal opportunities to advise government bodies
- Membership provides access to journals, continuing education, professional email addresses, training courses, insurance discounts, and sometimes even *shopping* discounts (the IOP give me a discount on the apple store!)
- There are tax incentives for membership in the UK (it often works out cheap, or cost-neutral)
- Academics often join to become eligible for grant funding from these bodies or to obtain a discount on attending a society-organised conference
- In medicine in particular, fellowships like FRCA are effectively  required to practice certain specialisms; MRCP at the minimum *is* required to practice as a doctor.
- Membership may come with indemnity insurance and other practical benefits for those in a particular area, again relevant for (academic) medicine.
- It provides access to facilities and (often quite prestigious)  buildings for academic conferences or social gatherings -- often at cost-price. I've organised conferences through the IOP and they literally charge delegates what the food costs, not even accounting for staff time. No commercial organisation does that. I was in the royal society last Thursday at an event organising by the UK government and invited to give my opinion on things. The food was excellent and I am sure that they got my name by searching through a list by research interest.

These are all benefits -- some of them much more tangible than others.